# How do I make 2 select boxes to dismiss each other if they mach and automatically select the second option to not match?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

How do I make 2 select boxes to dismiss each other if they match, by automatically selecting the second option?

I want it instead of "alert" to have a function that automatically changes one option to the second option on one of the select option boxes when they match.

If I can keep the alert and have it automatically change that would be ideal, but I accept if the alert can not be kept.

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
  'use strict';
  $('.OBSMatch').on('change', function (event) {
    var selectedValue = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    var matchedDropdowns = $('.OBSMatch').filter(function (index) {
      return $(this).val() === selectedValue;
    });
    if (matchedDropdowns.length > 1) {
      alert("OBS! You cannot use it, because it matches each other!")
    }
  })
})
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="LangF1" class="OBSMatch">
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option selected value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
</select>

<select name="LangF2" class="OBSMatch">
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option selected value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
</select>
```

**Update:** I added this update from the complete code because the former good answer is not working correctly because of this button that does  Switches the option languages.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getSelectedOption( elem ) {
  return elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
}

function setSelectedOption( elem, value ) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
    elem.options[i].selected = value === elem.options[i].value;
  }
}

function swapByOptionValue( selector1, selector2 ) {
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = getSelectedOption( elem1 ),
      selectedOption2 = getSelectedOption( elem2 );
  setSelectedOption( elem1, selectedOption2 );
  setSelectedOption( elem2, selectedOption1 );
}

function swapBySelectedIndex( selector1, selector2 ) {
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = elem1.selectedIndex;

  elem1.selectedIndex = elem2.selectedIndex;
  elem2.selectedIndex = selectedOption1;
}
</script>
<input type="button" id="SwitchLang" onClick="swapByOptionValue('select[name=\'LangF1\']', 'select[name=\'LangF2\']');" value=" Swap &#9650;&#9660; Language ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is an UI which allows the user to put the UI into an illegal state, gives an alert, and attempts to make things legal.

This really doesn't make for a great UI.

If at all possible, the user should be prevented from putting the UI into an illegal state, then there's no need for an alert and no need to correct anything. Such a strategy is eminently possible here.

The basic rules are fairly simple. On change of either select menu :

- the other menu's counterpart to this menu's current selection should be disabled.
- the other menu's other options should be enabled.
- any initially disabled options need to be protected from becoming enabled.

```
var $menus = $('.OBSMatch').on('change', function(event) {
    $menus.not(this).find('option').filter(function(index, opt) {
        return opt.value === event.target.value;
    }).prop('disabled', true) // disable the other menu's option corresponding to this menu's selection
    .siblings().not('._protected').prop('disabled', false); // enable the other menu's options except any that are protected.
});

$menus.find('option').filter(function(index, opt) {
    return opt.disabled;
}).addClass('_protected'); // protect any initially disabled options from being enabled

$menus.trigger('change'); // initialize everything
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uwf4dt54/1/)

"Auto Detect" may need to be handled as a special case - I'm not sure.

Alternatively, for a set of 3+ select menus ...

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uwf4dt54/2/)

---

Edit:

The two menu's selections can be switched as follows :

```
function switch_(selector) {
    var $menus = $(selector);
    var values = $menus.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().reverse(); // reverse() swaps the two values
    $menus.each(function(i, menu) {
        $(this).val(values[i]); // implement the switch
    }).trigger('change'); // re-initialize everything
}

// call
switch_('.OBSMatch');

// so, assuming you have a #switch element :
$('#switch').on('click', function() {
    switch_('.OBSMatch');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uwf4dt54/3/)

*The function can't be named `switch`, which is a javascript reserved word; therefore `switch_`*

Comment: Now I know why your answer did not work for me. You see I must have the language value only going once, not twice. The thing is that I only posted in the question a small part of the select option menu. The entire menu has over 40 languages and they are divided in most "common languages" and "all languages", there for the "common languages" repeat as values in the "all languages" area of the option list.

Comment: I solved that problem of not working cause it was twice the same value. But now it is a second problem, it goes wrong when languages are switched using the updated codes.

Comment: What do you mean by "switched " here?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to update the code for the switch. So please take a look at the update now and add that to the entire page. Now I added it and as you can see the switch switches the select options so that a person can use the languages the other way around. But now it is a second problem, it goes wrong when languages are switched using the updated codes.

Comment: Maybe somehow the options need to re-click itself so it takes in count the swap switch of languages too when the swap switch of language button is clicked. Th e other guys solution does not pose this problem, on the other hand your solution is much better with disabling the options instead of a alert. So it would feel a lot better if I make your idea of disabling the option to work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it tomorrow. Now it is late I need to go to sleep. After i test it, I will tell you if it worked...

Comment: Works good, except that when I reload the page I get the message quote "Confirm form Resubmission: The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?" And I need to click "Continue" of "Cancel".  But it should not pop up, it should be without a "Confirm form Resubmission" message... How do I fix that?

Comment: @SeekLoad, I think that's a separate issue. Nothing in this javascript/jQuery would cause that message to appear.

Comment: No problem, I solved it. It was some error code somewhere, but as soon as I used the backup and recopied and re-fixed all the codes to have new fresh codes on the page, all worked fine with your code. I guess there was a typo somewhere that I did not see. Thank you it works perfectly now.

Comment: I will, if I find a place when I am finished and uploaded the new page online, I will put a link to it as a comment to all the places I asked questions to get help making this page. It is a HUGE page with code encryption and decryption tools, with wed editing tools, mathematics tools and dictionaries with translators and over 50 different search categories with different search pages and options. But the design is made in such a way to keep it as simple in feeling as possible although it has a LOOOOOT of stuff.

Comment: The page I am working on is HUGE, but it is my flag ship webpage so it has to be much better this time. Last time I made the design it was in 2004 and back then the entire webpage language and design traditions were different to not mention it need so be smart phone capable now. Also now that old page online now is really bad compared with the modern pages. I need something also with less bugs, because of all the time passed the old page is 50% working with the pages online today. Now with this page in 2017 I want to bring the page back up from the dead.

Comment: Wow, can you give me a URL please?

Comment: This online today is "Version 9" and updated last in 2007 and made in 2004. The version I am now working on is called "version 17.10" and it is MUCH DIFFERENT from "version 9", to not say 100% different in programming and everything. That is because in 2010 till 2012 I went professionally at a IT university study and I studies as "IT Interaction Designer". So what I knew in 2004 resp 2007 is NOTHING compared to what I know today in 2017. The knowledge upgrade learning I made in this time is HUGE.

Comment: So PLEASE do NOT think that the page " http://www.seekload.50webs.com "; is the finished result, that one now is VERY OLD 2004, upgraded 2007 online the old page will be deleted, I will upload the new page made now in 2017 and that new page is 100% different. So PLEASE do not lough of the old page. Back then I did not have the knowledge of designing webpages that i have today. I also have this forum page online since 2007: " http://www.seekload.createaforum.com "; who needs a bit fixing too.

Comment: Here is a portfolio of other webpages I made online after 2007 till 2016 " http://seekload.50webs.com/Portfolio/Sites1.htm ", the SeekLoad search machine webpage is not in the portfolio because I am ashamed of it. It needs a serous remaking that soon will be uploaded. On the portfolio I say "we make" and not "I make" because some of the pages are not made alone, wile others are and I did not specify what is made by myself only and what is not.

Comment: These two web pages are also made by me: " http://tomas-skradderi.50webs.com " and " http://www.samurajsushibar.co.nr " (Samuraj Sushibar does not exist anymore since 2012 he closed down and moved to a bigger city in another country with more clients). On these pages I could not chose design, it was preferred by the owners of the companies I made it for. Both these pages were made in 2008. That is why that design and feeling. As I said, I advanced big time since 2007. Of course I made the logos and such according to the clients proposal... Exclude my pages.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

The key here is, on change:

- Get the value of target element
- Get the value of the related `select`
- If values match, change the value of target element to the next option

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $(function() {
  
    'use strict';
    
    $('.OBSMatch').on('change', function(event) {
    
      var selectedVal = $(event.currentTarget).val();
      var relatedId = $(this).attr('data-related');
      var $otherSelect = $('#' + relatedId);
      var otherVal = $otherSelect.val();

      if (selectedVal === otherVal) {
        
        $(this).val($(this).find('option:selected').next().val());
        
        // alert("OBS! You cannot use it, because it matches each other!");
        
      }
    })
    
  })
});

// UPDATE:  Added code from updated question to test solution along with rest of code:

function getSelectedOption( elem ) {
  return elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
}

function setSelectedOption( elem, value ) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i++) {
    elem.options[i].selected = value === elem.options[i].value;
  }
}

function swapByOptionValue( selector1, selector2 ) {
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = getSelectedOption( elem1 ),
      selectedOption2 = getSelectedOption( elem2 );
  setSelectedOption( elem1, selectedOption2 );
  setSelectedOption( elem2, selectedOption1 );
}

function swapBySelectedIndex( selector1, selector2 ) {
  var elem1 = document.querySelector(selector1),
      elem2 = document.querySelector(selector2),
      selectedOption1 = elem1.selectedIndex;

  elem1.selectedIndex = elem2.selectedIndex;
  elem2.selectedIndex = selectedOption1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="LangF1" class="OBSMatch" data-related="ddl2" id="ddl1">
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option selected value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option value="disabled" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
</select>

<select name="LangF2" class="OBSMatch" data-related="ddl1" id="ddl2">
<option value="zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option>
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
<option value="de">German</option>
<option value="ru">Russian</option>
<option value="es">Spanish</option>
<option selected value="disabled" disabled>&#8212;</option>
<option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
</select>

<!-- UPDATE:  Added code from updated question to test solution along with rest of code: -->

<input type="button" id="SwitchLang" onClick="swapByOptionValue('select[name=\'LangF1\']', 'select[name=\'LangF2\']');" value=" Swap &#9650;&#9660; Language ">
```

Comment: Shit I ran into a problem. It works PERFECTLY when it is used separately on a page for itself. But it refuses to work when implemented in the big page together with other JavaScript codes. :( I will fiddle with it more tomorrow now. It is late, good night...

Comment: @SeekLoad @ChavaG Updated code to find related element by using `data` attribute having target `id`.

Comment: Something is wrong. Play around with this for a while and you will find that some illegal states are not "corrected".

Comment: @Roamer-1888  You are right!  Some corner cases were not accounted for, previously.  I updated my example code so it covers any scenario.

Comment: The same problem, it does not work when I implemented it in the page, but it works when tested alone.

Comment: That's interesting.  Can you provide a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem?  (or just link to the page in question)

Comment: It's very odd @ChavaG. Your solution looks like it should be portable.

Comment: True, @Roamer-1888. I updated my snippet with the code SeekLoad added to his question.  I'ts all working here...